# Get all ticks values (NVD3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { 
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to get array of "d" variables which will be passed to this callbacks before it even executed? I need to analyze this array first to know which values to show on chart and which I should hide.

Or maybe I could correct this array and pass it to tickValues.

Comment: `chart.xAxis.ticks()`

Comment: @LarsKotthoff it returns some kind of a chart width. For example: "10.95". If I make chart smaller it will return something like: "7.65".

Comment: Hmm, turns out that NVD3 doesn't expose this D3 method, but overwrites it with its own method that doesn't set the tick values... From the source code, it looks like you should be able to get the tick values that are set automatically with `chart.xAxis.scale().ticks(Math.abs(chart.xAxis.scale().range()[1] - chart.xAxis.scale().range()[0]) / 100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVD3 doesn't expose the D3 method for getting tick values from a scale/axis, but overwrites it with its own method that doesn't set the tick values...

From [the source code](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/axis.js), it looks like you should be able to get the tick values that are set automatically with

```
chart.xAxis.scale()
     .ticks(Math.abs(chart.xAxis.scale().range()[1] - chart.xAxis.scale().range()[0]) / 100)
```

Note that this will only work for horizontal axes (i.e. x axes like in your case).

Comment: How could i do this on the y axis?

Comment: Replace `xAxis` with `yAxis` -- no idea if this still works though.